# Does the slave pseudoterminal use the line discipline?

Tags: linux, terminal, unix, tty

According to this [article](https://ishuah.com/2021/02/04/understanding-the-linux-tty-subsystem/#:%7E:text=the%20line%20discipline%20instance%20is%20not%20evoked%20when%20the%20TTY%20driver%20is%20sending%20user%20program%20output%20to%20PTY%20master):

> the line discipline instance is not evoked when the TTY driver is sending user program output to PTY master

and the [accompanying diagram](https://ishuah.com/images/pseudo-terminal.jpg).

However, according to a different [article](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php) (which is highly referenced), the line discipline does get evoked. Well actually, it is only inferred pictorially through this [diagram](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/case4.png).

In my opinion, the processes attached to the slave cannot send key presses like Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Z, so a tty line discipline is not necessary to generate corresponding POSIX signals. They also do not need character echoing, input history and completion, or line editing capabilities of the line discipline. The processes may however need automatic newline conversion, among many other similar capabilities. Infact, in the case of SLIP/PPP, the slave may need to evoke the SLIP/PPP line discipline for packet conversion.

So, is the first article wrong about the line discipline not getting evoked by the slave pseudo-device?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are right.

Both sides communicate using a specified discipline, just that the
discipline is defined as raw (no-op, null discipline) by default on one side,
in which case it does nothing more than pass the bytes.

Comment: by one side, you mean the slave end?

Comment: Yes. [15 chars]